# Why would this.setState not update the state object?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, state

I am running a simple method in a React component. After computing the values I wish to set them to the state object and rerender the component.

Here is the relevant code:

```
`class ManageAuthors extends Component {
  state = {authors: [], allAuthors: []};

  authorLists = allPotentialAuthors => {
    const allAuthors = allPotentialAuthors.map(mem => ({...mem, isCurrent: true});
    const authors = this.props.authors.filter({_some other filter code_});
    this.setState({authors, allAuthors});
};

  render() {
    const {authors, allAuthors} = this.state;
    console.log('state:', authors, allAuthors);
    return (
      <Query query={query}>
        {({loading, data}) => {
          if (!loading && data) {
            this.authorLists(data.authors)
          }
          return (_stuff to return_);
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  };
};`
```

The Query fires correctly and returns data and that data is sent to the `authorLists` method. Each of the const variables computes the correct values. But when the `this.setState` method should be called, nothing actually updates. It's like the `this.setState` method is not even firing. Is there something that would prevent the `this.setState` method from working/updating the local state object?

Comment: does your `console.log` in the render show you the value of state at all?

Comment: Yes, the `console.log` shows the original state: `state = {authors: [], allAuthors: []}` and never updates to `state = {authors: [...], allAuthors: [...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` does not always update the state right away. If you need access to that variable right away you can pass a function setState and play with that variable there.

For example:

```
this.setState({authors, allAuthors}, () => {
   //do something with authors or allAuthors or both
   console.log(authors); console.log(allAuthors); //log it to see if you get desired result
  }
);
```

React Documentation explains this pitfall:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied.

Can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Or search "setState" on React's documentation site.

Answer (score -1):

Correct below line :

```
this.setState({authors, allAuthors});
```

to

```
this.setState({authors: allAuthors});
```

Comment: I don't think so. This is short-hand for `this.setState({authors: authors, allAuthors: allAuthors})`. I don't want to set `authors = allAuthors` as they are two different arrays.